# Finding the closest points to a line with only one point from each subset of points

Tags: intersection, proximity, nearest-neighbor, qgis-2.18

I have a set of data points that represent many paths for different journeys, where each journey has its own identifier (Operation No). The data for all journeys is in a single table but in effect has multiple sub-sets of points for each individual journey. A sample of the data is shown below:

```
Operation No, Time Delay (seconds),  Latitude,  Longitude, Altitude (ft), Velocity (knots)
    16173263,                    0, 42.005191, -81.987368,         12444,                0
    16173263,                    1, 42.003938, -81.986167,         12418,            328.5
    16173263,                    5, 41.999006, -81.981324,         12303,            326.6
    16173263,                    9, 41.994118, -81.976394,         12182,            326.6
    16173263,                   13, 41.989301, -81.971414,         12054,            324.6
    16173263,                   17,  41.98452, -81.966409,         11919,            322.7
    16173263,                   21, 41.979784, -81.961404,         11778,            320.7
    16173263,                   25, 41.975057, -81.956437,         11637,            320.7
    16173263,                   29, 41.970348,  -81.95152,         11490,            318.8
    16173264,                    0, 41.512822, -82.082972,          5331,                0
    16173264,                    3, 41.513811, -82.078243,          5266,            258.5
    16173264,                    7, 41.515101, -82.071902,          5180,            258.5
    16173264,                   11, 41.516373, -82.065547,          5105,            258.5
    16173264,                   15, 41.517608, -82.059206,          5036,            258.5
    16173264,                   19, 41.518844, -82.052913,          4970,            256.6
    16173264,                   23, 41.520053,  -82.04672,          4905,            252.7
    16173264,                   27, 41.521254, -82.040638,          4846,            246.9
```

In the following image the points are styled with a different colour for each individual journey. I have put red circles around a couple of consecutive points from one journey and likewise blue circles around another pair of consecutive points from a different journey. The green line across the centre is a virtual gate and I would like to identify the closest point from each inidvidual journey to the green line. Crucially where a journey would not cross the line I do not need to identify the closest point. So in the image below for the two journey's identified with red and blue circles it would be the two points below the line.

[image: plot example]

If I join the points to create individual journey paths I loose the details of the attributes associated with the point closest to the line, although I can retain the individual journey identifiers. The value of the attributes is vital to the later analysis.